# Is it possible to calculate longitude / latitude of a point from a flat image

Tags: algorithm, maps, coordinates

I have a game, where there is a planet, and that planet have points where people can build items. The point must be on solid ground and not in the water.

I create a texture blue/green, that I  apply on a sphere in the client. But I would like the server to generate the points based on that texture (and not generate them client side).

I thought of doing so by having the current texture on the server, then "scan" with some precision (amount of point) the map, so specific pixel, and based on the color define if it's a green or blue point (so land or not).

[image]

Is there some algorithm that, using a flat texture, can calculate long/lat point, so that I check if it's land or not, and when I wrap the texture around a sphere I can then just use the same long/lat to draw those points.

Comment: Yes, there are methods. From a flat map (e.g. mercator), how do you build a view as yours? Do just the inverse (point x,y in your projection to coordinates).

Comment: Excuse me, what do you mean by " how do you build a view as yours", how do I build the map or the sphere ? or the point on the sphere ? 

yes my plan was to get x/y position and transform them in coordinate. The problem with that is that I will have more density in the point on top, and less in the center, I have to arrange this part, but my main plan will be similar 

=> get map => get point x/y => check if land/water => convert x/y to long/lat => save the data

Comment: I think I interpreted the question wrongly (but the title confuse me). What it is your starting point? Do you have a map? In 3D or just an image (so already projected?) In which projection? The problem is to find if a point it is in water, or about getting coordinates from a projection (like in the above images: they are 2D projection)?

Comment: Sorry if it's confusing.

I have a map, I have a sphere, and I can wrap my texture around the sphere.

But, the thing is, I am doing a multiplayer game, and I would like to generate the point on the server, and not on the client. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/174899/how-to-generate-point-based-on-a-map?noredirect=1#comment311383_174899

I am trying to find solution for doing this,generate the point on the server side (based on land/water) and display them at the exact position they should be in the client.

Comment: One solution would be to generate the point based on a texture, so calculating long/lat point, check the (water/land), then storing those point with long/lat and I would have a easy way to redisplay them at the exact position in the Client